# "misplaced construct(s)" in Java code near a catch

Tags: java

I could not compile the following code in Java, error is: misplaced construct(s). What's wrong?

```
public class ExceptionsTutorial {

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception{

        try{
            System.out.println("A");

            try{
                System.out.println("B");
                throw new Exception("1");
            }
            catch{
                System.out.println("C");
                throw new Exception("2");
            }
            finally{
                System.out.println("D");
                throw new Exception("3");
            }

        }
        finally{
            System.out.println("F");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What are the compiler errors?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`catch` must declare what exception it catches:

```
catch (Exception E) {
 System.out.println("C");
 throw new Exception("2");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Read up on Java [catch blocks](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).  There is a required element that is missing in your code.

Note that Java's behavior is slightly different from that of C# or Python in this regard.

Comment: I misread your answer and assumed you were talking about the lack of a **catch** clause.  Sorry for the downvote; can't take it back now unless you edit.

Comment: Thanks, akf.  I should have realized I could have edited it myself.  My brain is a little slow right now; time for lunch, I guess.